# Can a DV CA issue IP certificate

Tags: certificate-authority

I understand that according to CA/B, CA can issue certificate to a public IP address if the validation challenge is satisfied. But can a DV CA issue IP certificates? (If their CA policy allows) Does CA/B allow a DV CA to issue IP certificate?

(Since most CA providers only issue IP certificate to OV identity...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually thought CAs can't issue DV certificate to IPs due to CA/B regulation and was surprised when I got a free certificate that contains IP address as a SAN. That's why I posted this question (and bugged https://stackexchange.com/users/1513078/scott-helme on Twitter, as well as create a Bugzilla request). It turns out I'm wrong.

Quote from Wayne (from Mozilla Bugzilla):

> BR section 3.2.2.5.1 permits CAs to issue DV certificates for IP
>   addresses via 'HTTP file validation' as follows:
>
> Confirming the Applicant's control over the requested IP Address by
>   confirming the presence of a Request Token or Random Value contained
>   in the content of a file or webpage in the form of a meta tag under
>   the "/.well-known/pki-validation" directory, or another path
>   registered with IANA for the purpose of validating control of IP
>   Addresses, on the IP Address that is accessible by the CA via
>   HTTP/HTTPS over an Authorized Port. The Request Token or Random Value
>   MUST NOT appear in the request.
>   3.2.2.5.1. Agreed-Upon Change to Website If a Random Value is used, the CA SHALL provide a Random Value unique to the certificate request
>   and SHALL not use the Random Value after the longer of (i) 30 days or
>   (ii) if the Applicant submitted the certificate request, the timeframe
>   permitted for reuse of validated information relevant to the
>   certificate (such as in Section 4.2.1 of this document).

So CA could issue IP certificates under the new BR (Specific: Ballot SC7 that passed in Feb 2019. https://cabforum.org/2019/02/09/ballot-sc7-update-ip-address-validation-methods/) that only complete the HTTP DCV.

The ultimate answer to my own question: Yes CA/B does allow IPs to be included as SAN for DV certificate (given it passes the validation requirement).

Answer (score 2):

> Does CA/B allow a DV CA to issue IP certificate?

No, CAB Forum baseline requirements don't mention DV or OV requirements for IP addresses. However, DV certificate issuance to IP address is not allowed by validation procedures. You will have to prove that you own specified public IP address. IANA and delegated regional registrars (RIPE, ARIN, etc.) lease IP addresses only to organizations. As private person, you can lease IP address from ISP, but you can't prove to CA that you own this IP address. Therefore, private persons can't pass IP address ownership validation procedures.

Here is a link to relevant CAB Forum page: https://cabforum.org/2019/02/09/ballot-sc7-update-ip-address-validation-methods/

And some excerpts:

> **IP Address Contact:** The person(s) or entity(ies) registered with an IP Address Registration Authority as having the right to control how one or more IP Addresses are used.
>
> **IP Address Registration Authority:** The  Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) or a Regional Internet Registry (RIPE, APNIC, ARIN, AfriNIC, LACNIC).
>
> <...>
>
> The CA MAY send the email, fax, SMS, or postal mail identified under this section to more than one recipient provided that every recipient is identified by the IP Address Registration Authority as representing the IP Address Contact for every IP Address being verified using the email, fax, SMS, or postal mail.

Given this, as long as you are not identified by IP address registrar, you barely can prove that you own the IP address in the request.